# How to set noindex on components

Tags: component, seo

Anyone who can tell me how I can disable the component users to provide search engines the noindex, means:

```
<meta name=robots content="noindex" />
```

for example in all Joomla instances, the URL

```
/component/users/
```

Is there a common way to set the noindex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have activated `Search Engine Friendly URLs`

in this case you need to add to your `robots.txt`

```
User-agent: *
# disallow login from of joomla
Disallow: /component/users/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `robots.txt` file to disallow the indexing. Try using this directive in your `robots.txt` file.

```
User-agent: *    
Disallow: /*?option=com_users*
```

The **cons** of this approach is that not all search engines crawlers observe the wildcard syntax. I think this will do the trick with the major ones (Google, Bing and Yahoo).

I found [this](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2008/06/improving-on-robots-exclusion-protocol.html) and [this](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt) useful articles about robots.

Another way that you could try is in every menu item, that calls the com_users component, in the *metadata* tab, set the *robots* option to *No Index*.