# How to make Category Links noindex

Tags: url, seo, category

Is there a way to make all my categories to be "noindex"? (Plugin or even better default joomla way)

Right now crawlers find the category URLs and thus create duplicate content on search engines.

Would be great to have one central config for all categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the same problem I went down to the database.

with this SQL you can update **ALL** categories to noindex and to nofollow for search engines (google, bing, yandex)

```
UPDATE `jos_categories` SET `metadata`='{"author":"","robots":"noindex, nofollow"}' WHERE `extension`='com_content'
```

you need to find out your table prefix, in the above example jos_ is the default prefix of joomla. If your table prefix is xzhw_ of course your SQL would be

```
UPDATE `xzhw_categories` SET `metadata`='{"author":"","robots":"noindex, nofollow"}' WHERE `extension`='com_content'
```

**be careful**

if you use categories for displaying other content in e.g. a category blog, **DO NOT USE THE SQL**. Instead you should eiher select your categories in the WHERE clause or even better you go manually through the categories in the backend of joomla and you edit under Publish-tab the Robots to noindex, nofollow

Comment: thank you, tested it with phpmyadmin. worked great and reduces a lot of manual work if you have a bunch of categories!

Answer (score 2):

You can walk through all categories, and in the `Publishing` tab, set the `Robots` option to No Index.

Comment: is there a default setting on joomla to make this as a default for all categories?

Comment: @cilap In Joomla Global Configuration in the `Site` tab, set the `Robots` option to No Index, **but this will affect all Joomla content, not only the categories**. You can also try the use of `robots.txt`. See my answer to [this question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24293/how-to-set-noindex-on-components).

Comment: sadly the global setting will not help in my case since all of joomla articles would also go to noindex.